# ApolloClient - How to pass array instead of string?

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-client, react-apollo

On the GraphQL Playground, this query works so backend is fine:

```
query ($CatIDs: [String]) {
  categories(where: { id: $CatIDs }) {
    id
  Name
  slug
    collections {
    id
    slug
    Name
    Description
    }
  }
}
```

Where the variable $CatIDs is:

```
["7","9","13","14"]
```

Now in ApolloClient, which I use with NextJS/React, I pass the array this way:

```
   const { data: SubCategory } = await client.query({
    query: getSubCategories,
    variables: {
      CatIDs
  },
  });
```

The problem is when I do that in ApolloClient, I think CatIDs get's wrapped in an additional quotation marks which makes it a String?

Or what could be the problem?

Error:

> ApolloError: select distinct "categories".* from "categories" where
> (("categories"."id" = $1)) and ("categories"."published_at" is not
> null) limit $2 - invalid input syntax for type integer:
> "["7","9","13","14"]"

**Edit:**

I see now when I set the array manually, I get a valid response.

```
 variables: {
      CatIDs: ["1", "2", "3"]
  },
```

So there must be something wrong with when I set CatIDs, even though when I log it, the value looks fine.

This is how I set CatIDs:

1. Initial Response-Object:

```
  { __typename: 'Category', id: '7' },
  { __typename: 'Category', id: '9' },
  { __typename: 'Category', id: '13' },
  { __typename: 'Category', id: '14' }
```

2. Map over IDs:

```
var CatIDs = SubCatIDs.map (x => x.id);

[ '7', '9', '13', '14' ]
```

3. JSON.stringify to get double-quotations:

```
CatIDs = JSON.stringify(CatIDs);

["7","9","13","14"]
```

4. Query with CatIDs -> Error

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

1. Don't need JSON.stringify
2. First entry in variables needs to be in double-quotations

```
const { data: SubCategory } = await client.query({
    query: getSubCategories,
    variables: {
      "CatIDs": CatIDs
    },
  });
```